# Installing dgen removes ubuntu-desktop

Tags: package-management, dependencies, emulation

I am trying to install "dgen" a Sega MegaDrive/Genesis emulator, available in the official Ubuntu repositories. But when I try to install, the package manager (USC or even apt-get), say's that he needs to remove those packages before installing :

```
file-roller lintian ubuntu-desktop unzip winetricks
```

So, How can I install this package without removing those packages ?
And do I need to fill a bug report for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the package, you need to file a bug on dgen:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dgen/+filebug
```

And then add the information of the packages it's trying to remove.

OP has filed the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dgen/+bug/1016944

Comment: How can I use ubuntu-bug on a package that I don't have installed ?

Comment: Good point, updated!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, just one last question.. I've detected that the problem is principaly because of the unzip:i386 package that need to remove ubuntu-desktop... So do I need to fill a bug report on unzip only or on unzip and dgen since he uses it too ?

Comment: Probably dgen itself, removing ubuntu-desktop won't hurt anything though, but still it shouldn't do that. It's probably related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dgen/+bug/997335

Comment: This is the principal cause : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unzip/+bug/1010450 , thanks for you help anyway :D